# Erroneous .whl file naming when installing bpy

Tags: python, transparency

I am running the latest release of blender (4.1.0a0) alpha and the naming of the .whl file that the make_bpy_whl.py script does is erroneous and pip won't let me install. It produces a file named bpy-4.1.0a0-cp311-cp311m-win_amd64.whl. The 'm' suffix was used in Python to indicate it was compiled with pymalloc, a specialized allocator for Python objects. However, starting from Python 3.8, the m and d (debug) ABI flags have been removed from the filename for simplicity. The presence of this tag in a wheel meant for Python 3.11 is unusual, as Python packaging has evolved to simplify these tags.
I am running the latest version of pip 24.0 and the tags it recognizes (found using pip debug --verbose) are

```
cp311-cp311-win_amd64
cp311-abi3-win_amd64
cp311-none-win_amd64
```

none of which align with the naming convention of the .whl file blender created. I can't find anything out there so might next best hunch is to just rename the file.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but we can't help with unreleased versions of Blender and in any case there are no Blender developers here. Suggest you ask on the Blender [Developer Forum](https://devtalk.blender.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that somehow my `PATH` was set to my Python 3.7 install first before my Python 3.11. I rebuilt the wheel using the correct path and it removed the suffix `m` from the file name. This makes sense since that was an artifact from Python 3.7. Now pip can recognize this and I have installed my `bpy 4.1.0a0` module successfully.